# Arduino void loop does not loop

Tags: arduino

I am trying to blink an Array of LEDs hooked up to a pin on the Arduino.

When I upload the code onto my Arduino :

```
//array of pins
int allLEDPins[4] = {2, 3, 4, 5};

//the chase function
void Chaster(int* anArray) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    digitalWrite(allPins[i], HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(allPins[i], LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
}

//setup pins
void setup() {
  pinMode(allPins[0], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(allPins[1], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(allPins[2], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(allPins[3], OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  Chaster(allLEDPins);
}
```

The loop function does not loop. I am using an Arduino Zero in Arduino IDE 1.6.8 on my Windows 10 machine. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing an index out of range in the for loop inside the function `Chaster`. Note that your array `allLEDPins` have only 4 elements and you tried to access `allLEDPins[4]` while the last element is `allLEDPins[3]`. This causes an error during running time.

In order to fix that, replace `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` by `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

Comment: Thank you. By changing the for loop, it all worked out!